# Why try catch around highchart constructor does not catch error#12 but error#19?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts 4.0.4 and trying to catch any error that occurs during rendering.

I was able to catch the error#19, but  when error#12 occurs the control doesn't go to the catch block. Does anyone know what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Function call for the error #12 is done without second function argument `error(12);`. The second function argument is responsible for stopping the code execution, so the code is not stopped.

Code from Highcharts 4.0.4:

```
/**
 * Provide error messages for debugging, with links to online explanation 
 */
error = function (code, stop) {
    var msg = 'Highcharts error #' + code + ': www.highcharts.com/errors/' + code;
    if (stop) {
        throw msg;
    }
    // else ...
    if (win.console) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
};
```

In Highcharts 5.0.0+ it is possible to [override/extend/wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) the error function with you own code.